# Methods for increasing output power and efficiency of a ZVS flyback driver

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, high-voltage, driver, flyback

I have built the following ZVS driver:
[image]

I am using this circuit at a resonance frequency of 150kHz.

My hope is to be able to modify this circuit for wireless power transmission. With that being said, I will only be applying a maximum of 20V DC to this circuit at the input. From testing the circuit with that voltage, the output power is very low, barely turning on a small LED light. Can anyone request any ideas for changes or modifications to achieve better output power?

I am new to building circuits so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What current was it drawing from the 20V supply?

Comment: @BrianDrummond 69mA with no load and 70mA with load

Comment: Looks like you need to improve coupling between the transmitter and receiver.

Comment: You need to show the precise circuit and coupling method you chose.